# Non-linear regression line and R² in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, nonlinear-functions

I have the following data:

```
dput(dat)
structure(list(Band = c(1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 
1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930, 1930
), Reflectance = c(25.296494, 21.954657, 18.981184, 15.984661, 
14.381341, 12.485372, 10.592539, 8.51772, 7.601568, 7.075429, 
6.205453, 5.36646, 4.853167, 4.21576, 3.979639, 3.504217, 3.313851, 
2.288752), Number.of.Sprays = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 
14, 17, 19, 21, 27, 30, 36, 49), Legend = structure(c(4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L
), .Label = c("1 x spray between each measurement", "2 x spray between each measurement", 
"3 x spray between each measurement", "Dry soil", "Wet soil"), class = "factor")), .Names =c("Band", 
"Reflectance", "Number.of.Sprays", "Legend"), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), class = "data.frame")
```

which results in the following plot

[image]

with the following code

```
g <- ggplot(dat, aes(Number.of.Sprays, Reflectance, colour = Legend)) +
    geom_point (size = 3) +
    geom_smooth (aes(group = 1, colour = "Trendline"), method = "loess", size = 1, linetype = "dashed", se = FALSE) +
    stat_smooth(method = "nls", formula = "y ~ a*x^b", start = list(a = 1, b = 1), se = FALSE)+
    theme_bw (base_family = "Times") +
    labs (title = "Regression between Number of Sprays and Reflectance in Band 1930") +
    xlab ("Number of Sprays") +
    guides (colour = guide_legend (override.aes = list(linetype = c(rep("blank", 4), "dashed", "blank"), shape = c(rep(16, 4), NA, 16)))) +
    scale_colour_manual (values = c("cyan", "green2", "blue", "brown",  "red", "purple")) +
    theme (legend.title = element_text (size = 15), legend.justification = c(1,1),legend.position = c(1,1), legend.background = element_rect (colour = "black", fill = "white"))
```

Note: I don´t really get my `stat_smooth` line and the start feature in it, just adapted it from another thread.

Now my questions and aims:

1. Is there a package/function which can provide a more or less accurate estimation of which line-functions fits best to the points? Or do I have to try various function formulas and see which gives the best fit? The "Trendline" based on `method = "loess"` looks pretty good but I don´t know on what base it is calculated.
2. Why does my line applied through `stat_smooth()` depend on the factor levels in the data and does not simply rely on all points?
3. Why does the dashed legend icon for "Trendline" look so bad? (How can I change this?)
4. If I have a fitting non-linear regression line here at any time, how can I calculate R² on it? (I know R² is not that "good" on non-linear relations but I want to do it anyhow). `summary(lm())` only does it for linear relation. Is there a possibility to calculate R² based on the formula of the non-linear regression line?

I know thats a lot of questions and maybe some of them are more statistical related than directly to R. Couldn´t find answers to them in the other questions so just edit if something is not ok in this question.

Thanks for all your help,
Patrick

Comment: 1) The function you pass to `nls` should be chosen based on the science behind your data. `loess` is a smoother, i.e., a non-parametric fit. 2) Because you mapped `colour = Legend`. 3) What do you mean by "bad"? 4) https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-July/023461.html

Comment: 1) okay, so there is no "function" or tool which can do this for me? For Excel you can use http://www.nutonian.com/products/eureqa/ as an example. 2) That makes sense. If I remove it, my code does not work anymore and I get a strange error message =/ 3) I mean that the Icon does not look consistent in thickness and there is one big line and little dot. Would prefer/expect 2 equal dashes as a symbol? 4) Thank you!

Comment: 1) I mean that you shouldn't use such a tool.

Answer (score 0):

1) Maybe I missunderstood de question, but I think that what you are asking for is for a rational and semi-automatic way to estimate the best starting points for the NLS method, given than the `loess` method doesn't provide you a model expression you can use in the future.

If this is the case, there I go. In your equation, `a` needs to be relatively close to the expected value of `Reflectance` when the `Number of Sprays = 0`, and `b` should give an idea of the decline in `Reflectance` with the `Number of Sprays` so the Gauss-Newton algotihm could do well it's job. The values of `a` and `b` does not need to be too aquarate. You can try the following:

```
fit = lm ( data = dat, Reflectance ~ Number.of.Sprays )
```

Then, in your `ggplot` call, I would replace your `geom_smooth` statement by:

```
stat_smooth(method = "nls", formula = "y ~ a*x^b",  method.args = list(start=c(a=fit$coefficients[[1]], b=fit$coefficients[[2]])), se = FALSE)
```

The warning concerning the starting values of the NLS method will diseappear, and it will converge just fine.

4) As a measure of the godness of the fitting, I suggest you to calculate the correlation between your observed values and your predicted values. Note that when an intercept is included, then R2 is simply the square of the sample correlation coefficient between the observed outcomes and the observed predictor values. So this should work for you:

```
r2 =  cor (dat$Reflectance, predict(fit))^2
```

2,3) As for these minor questions, I cannot provice a straight answer, or I do not understand them well. The lines in your plot are based on the levels of the factor `Legend` when you use it as aesthetic, not otherwise.